# Keep popup opened on spiderfy events with leaflet.markerClusterGroup?

Tags: leaflet, markers

With the [markerClusterGroup](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) leaflet plugin, calling the [spiderfy](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) function twice automatically closes the opened popup.

This seems to be due to [this piece of code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/499f71caa1fe8a4efcf91b85e42553f9a90306f1/src/MarkerCluster.Spiderfier.js#L313) in the `unspiderfy` function, that is called automatically by the second `spiderfy` call.

```
var tiles = L.tileLayer(...);
var map = L.map(...);
var coords = Array(...);
var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup();
var markers = Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var c = coords[i];
  var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]));
  markers.push(marker)
  marker.bindPopup("Point " + i);
  mcg.addLayer(marker);
}

function openPoint(i) {
    var marker = markers[i];
     var cluster = mcg.getVisibleParent(marker);
    if(cluster && cluster.spiderfy) {
        cluster.spiderfy();
    }
}

map.addLayer(mcg);

var x = ...;
var y = ...;
openPoint(x)            // Spiderfies the point x
markers[x].openPopup(); // Opens the popup for the point x
openPoint(y)            // Spiderfies the point y, and sadly closes the previous popup
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azmeuk/x7e8vc5p/2/) that illustrates the behavior I describe. Just click on buttons to spiderfy groups of items. Open a popup. And then click on another button to spiderfy another group of items. And see that the popup is closing.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve the behavior you want. One is to edit `Leaflet.markercluster` plugin code.

The other way is to reopen popup after it's undesirably closed. Drawback of this method is that popup blinks and the whole method is a bit hackish, but it can be done relatively simply.

That's how it goes:

1. With the help of `clustermouseover` and `clustermouseout` event processing it's checked on `popupclose` event if popup was closed because of spiderfy event. If yes, popup is reopened.
2. With the help of `unspiderfied` event, popup is opened which was closed during this action.

Relevant code could then look something like this (tested, but not very thoroughly, so there might still be some logic missing):

```
var reopenPopup = false;
var closedPopup = null;

var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup();
var markers = Array();

function onClick(evt) {
    var marker = markers[evt.target.dataset.markerid];
    var cluster = mcg.getVisibleParent(marker);
    if(cluster && cluster.spiderfy) {
      reopenPopup = true;
      cluster.spiderfy();
      reopenPopup = false;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var a = addressPoints[i];
  var title = a[2];
  var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title });
  markers.push(marker)
  marker.bindPopup(title);
  marker.on('popupclose', function(evt) {
    closedPopup = evt.target;
    if (reopenPopup) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        closedPopup.openPopup();
        closedPopup = null;
      }, 0);
      }
    else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        closedPopup = null;
      }, 500);
    }
  });
  mcg.addLayer(marker);
  
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  var content = document.createTextNode(i);
  button.appendChild(content);
  document.getElementById("buttons").appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener("click", onClick);
  button.dataset.markerid = i;
}

map.addLayer(mcg);

mcg.on('clustermouseover', function(evt) {
  reopenPopup = true;
});
mcg.on('clustermouseout', function(evt) {
  reopenPopup = false;
});
mcg.on('unspiderfied', function(evt) {
  if (closedPopup) {
    closedPopup.openPopup();
    closedPopup = null;
  }
});
```